# C# Unity 2D Topdown Movement Script not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have been working on a unity project where the player controls a ship. I was following along with a tutorial and have made an input script and a movement script that are tied together with unity's event system. As far as I can tell my script and the script in the tutorial are the same, but the tutorial script functions and mine doesn't.

Script to get player input

```
    using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System;
using UnityEngine.Events;

public class PlayerInput : MonoBehaviour
{
    
    public UnityEvent<Vector2> OnBoatMovement = new UnityEvent<Vector2>();
    public UnityEvent OnShoot = new UnityEvent();


    void Update()
    {
        BoatMovement();
        Shoot();
    }

    private void Shoot()
    {
       if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.F))
        {
            OnShoot?.Invoke();
        }
    }

    private void BoatMovement()
    {
        Vector2 movementVector = new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
        OnBoatMovement?.Invoke(movementVector.normalized);
    }
}
```

Script to move player

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Events;

public class Movement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody2D rb2d;
    private Vector2 movementVector;
    public float maxspeed = 10;
    public float rotatespeed = 50;
    private void Awake()
    {
        rb2d = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

    }
    public void HandleShooting()
    {
        Debug.Log("Shooting");
    }
    public void Handlemovement(Vector2 movementVector)
     {
        this.movementVector = movementVector;
     }
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rb2d.velocity = (Vector2)transform.up * movementVector.y * maxspeed * Time.deltaTime;
        rb2d.MoveRotation(transform.rotation * Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, -movementVector.x * rotatespeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime));
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach your Handlers (HandleShooting and Handlemovement) to corresponding events. Easiest way would be to make events static in PlayerInput

```
public static UnityEvent<Vector2> OnBoatMovement = new UnityEvent<Vector2>();
public static UnityEvent OnShoot = new UnityEvent();
```

and attach corresponding handlers to them in Movement.Awake

```
private void Awake(){
    rb2d = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    PlayerInput.OnBoatMovement += Handlemovement;
    PlayerInput.OnShoot += HandleShooting;
}
```

Also in PlayerInput.BoatMovement you should probably check

```
if(movementVector.sqrMagnitude > 0){
    OnBoatMovement?.Invoke(movementVector.normalized);
}
```

Or else random shit may happen when trying to normalize Vector with magnitude 0 (I compare sqr magnitude to aviod calculating root which is never desired)